# compiling user space code in linux

Tags: linux, compilation

A very basic question to which I could not find an answer by searching on the internet.

Basically, I want to know:

1. how the compiler differentiates a user space code from the kernel space code?
2. Is the makefile differnt for compiling user space code compared to kernel space code ?

Best regards,
Kutty

Answer (score 0):

The compiler just follows flags you pass to it, the rest is as usual and nothing magic.

For a small example, look at [Writing Your Own Loadable Kernel Module](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Module-HOWTO/x839.html). See also [Modules vs. Program](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x427.html).

The difference is of course in how those modules and programs are treated by the OS and which permissions they have (see also [rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28computer_security%29)).

Comment: Thank you. This would mean the Makefile syntax doesn't differentiate between the kernel and userspace code. Right?